# what does ' */ ' mean in CSS?

Tags: css

I don't know if this is good question but didn't find anywhere any answers, in my code when using `margin-top: -17px; * /` and `margin-top: -17px;` it gives me different results, what is the meaning of `*/` and are there more of these kind ?

Comment: looks like half of a css `/*comment*/`

Comment: Sounds like the "different result" might be due to a syntax error...

Comment: @Siguza you can try it here : https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_layout_float         take padding away from header and footer then go to div.container put margin-top: -17px; */ and without different results

Answer (score 3):

You can create comment sections in CSS and JS with `/* comment */`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments

Seems someone forgot to delete the end of a commented line.

Answer (score 3):

`*/` is the closing comment, therefor in `margin-top: -17;*/` CSS will not understand it and finally you won't get an expected output. For a meaningful script use `margin-top:-17;`

Answer (score 2):

we use 
*/ for insert comment in CSS codes

```
/* comments */
```

Comment: Careful with languages, friend. `<!-- Comment -->` is an _HTML_ comment. `/* Comment */` is a _CSS_ comment. PHP and JS expand on CSS comments allowing `// Comment` as well, and PHP even allows `# Comment`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment for CSS. You need to use it to make the code usable and readable. For example

```
/* minus margin */
margin-top: -17px;
```

If you using clone code

```
/* some code here
margin-top: -17px */
```

you used it in the wrong way